# How to clear MySQL screen console in Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, sqlcommand

The title is my question. I googled and try something like

```
mysql> !\ clear
mysql> !\ cls
mysql> system cls
mysql> system clear 

blah blah ...
```

but none of them works.

Anyone show me how to clear screen, just like `cls` command in Windows?

Comment: Hi friend can you try this [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html), so that this might help you

Comment: `system clear` works now

Comment: For Windows 11 on PowerShell running MySQL 8, `system cls` is work Fine.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is not possible on Windows.

There is an open bug for this issue: [Bug #58680: Windows Clear Screen Command](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680)

Comment: In linux Ctrl-L will worked fine but for window there is no any option.

Comment: They are probably in no rush to fix it, since Linux users usually look down their noses at Windows users, whom they perceive as second class citizens.

Comment: This is not a fix but pressing Enter until I get the cursor down eases my mind.

Comment: "system cls" clears the MySQL screen on PowerShell 7.

Answer (score 56):

You are typing the command wrong. It is `\` before `!` and not after.

The command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will not work for Windows. To clear MySQL console screen, type the following command:

```
mysql> \! cls
```

Explanation:

- `\!` is used to execute *system shell* commands
- `cls` is a command to clear the Windows command prompt screen

This will do the job for Windows.

---

Similarly if you are on Linux, you will type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or the following:

```
mysql> \! clear
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: Works with "\! cls" in Windows 10, thank you!

Comment: this answer is working fine in Windows 10. Commenting just for helping purpose.

Comment: also works on ubuntu - if anyone is interested

Answer (score 52):

I don't think Any of the commands will work.

In Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will do the job. In Windows there is no equivalent. You can only exit MySQL console by executing `quit`, execute `cls` and then re-enter MySQL console.

Answer (score 36):

```
mysql> 
root@xion:~# mysql -uroot -ppassword;
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 33291
Server version: 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.4 (Ubuntu)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> \! clear
```

Answer (score 11):

Just scroll down with your mouse

In Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will do but if your scroll up you will see the old commands

So I would suggest scrolling down in windows using mouse

Comment: It works also for windows PowerShell

Answer (score 9):

On linux : you can use <kbd>ctrl + L</kbd> or type command `system clear`.

Answer (score 5):

although there is bug for clearing the screen in MySQL, I have found one tactic trick whatever you want to say...

you can easily clear the screen using this...

just press ( ctrl + down arrow ) until you reach to top... happy codding...

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to get around this bug. The windows console (cmd) is just not worth using for anything other than some simple commands. So the following is what I did.

Installed Cygwin (Go [here](http://www.cygwin.com/)) It is pretty straight forward to install. You can watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTeH7vm8JZU). It explains very easily how to install cygwin. Make sure when you select the packages that you want to install includes Mintt (it is basically a better shell or cmd) and mysql client package.

Once you are done installing it, you should add the bin folder from cygwin in your PATH Environmental Variables(The above video explains that as well)

Now You will have an icon on the desktop for cygwin. Open it up and login to mysql using the normal commands. You will need to put the ip of the mysql server in the command to make it work. I use the following logging in MySQL which was installed through wamp

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

You can add more arguments in there if you want. Once you get in mysql just press ctrl + L and you will clear the screen.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: This works for me (MySQL console in Cmder on Windows 10)

Comment: you can Use the command system cls and this will clear the MYSQL Command Line window in Windows

Answer (score 4):

mysql console can cleared out on windows by using shortcut key

CTRL + L

Answer (score 3):

For `windows` user just type `system cls;`

*Note* don't forgot to add semicolon `;` at the last.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can clear the screen no matter whether you're using `Command line Client` or any `Linux Terminal` 
We're using `cls` in ***cmd*** and `clear` in ***terminal*** to clear the screen.
***Command line client*** and ***Terminal*** accepts the same command with either ***system*** or ***\!*** flag.
Both commands listed below are valid!

> ##### Command Line Client:
>
> ```
> system cls
> ```
>
> ```
> \! cls
> ```

> ##### For Terminal:
>
> ```
> system clear;
> ```
>
> ```
> \! clear;
> ```

> Other commands can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html) for ***MySql Command Line Client***
> Change the version number form the top right corner on the website.

Answer (score 2):

just type `\system cls`

took me a couple hours to get it jejej

Answer (score 1):

***Well, if you installed MySql Server e.g. Version 5.5. which has it's folder located in:***

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

The best way would be to include it in your paths.

- First run ***`sysdm.cpl`*** applet from ***`run`*** i.e. <kbd>WinKey + R</kbd>
- Navigate to ***Advanced -> Environment Variables***
- Select ***PATH*** and Click Edit.
- Scroll to the end of the text, and add ***";C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"*** without quotes (Notice the semicolon starting the text, this should only be added if it's not already there),

Now you can just call:

> start /b /wait mysql -u root -p

via command prompt.

To clear the screen now, you can just `exit` in mysql & call *`cls`*

*Kinda trickish hack but does the job.*

**If you're using WAMP or other tool, it's even easier!**

Open command prompt and type:

> C:\wamp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p

Enter as normal, then whenever you want to clear screen, do:

> exit *or* quit

And then clear using DOS:

> cls

*You can easily re-enter by pressing up twice to get your mysql call command*

Answer (score 1):

you can type the following step:

mysql> exit;

C:\xampp\mysql\bin> cls

C:\xampp\mysql\bin> mysql -u root -h localhost

it's work!

Answer (score 1):

I handle it as follows:

1. Right click on cmd open property's goto layout
2. Set screen buffer height to 9999 and ok
3. Now whenever you want to type a new query, just scroll with the mouse and you will get a blank screen

Answer (score 1):

SQL> clear scr

This command clears the screen in MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in Windows, It is not possible. The only way out is to exit and type cls and then again open mySQL

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using this:

```
clear screen
```

Answer (score 1):

For windows command prompt

Use

```
system cls
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug on Windows which most people are talking is probably fixed.
Ctrl + L is works for clearing the screen on Windows 10 [Mysql 8]

Answer (score 0):

Open Properties by clicking the upper left console window icon, go to Layout tab, take note of the value set in `Screen Buffer Size->Height`, and change it to 1. Click OK.
You'll see a 1 row console. Open Properties again and change that value back to what it had before. Resize the console down and you'll have a clean console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 8.0.19.

Previously, the system (!) command for the mysql command-line client
worked only for Unix and Unix-like systems. It now works on Windows
as well. For example, system cls or ! cls may be used to clear the
screen.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command line client prompt and to clear the screen I typed:-

**system cls**

Comment: add a short explanation why this answer is better or how this works. it makes answers better.

Comment: My possible explanation would be that I tried running all others including ctrl+L but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For Window 10

Use the command system cls and this will clear the MYSQL Command Line window in Windows

Answer (score 0):

As of 26 July, 2019. This issue has been fixed.

Use can either of them with out without semicolon to clear mysql console on windows.

1. `system cls`
2. `\! cls`

Source:
[Bug #58680 Windows Clear Screen Command](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680)

Answer (score 0):

This one ***worked*** for me

```
system cls;
```

Comment: This answer has been posted at least five other times on this same question. Adding more to the pile doesn't really help.

Answer (score -1):

Click with contextMenu button on Mysql prompt and choose "Scroll", because I didn't find any way to clean too. =P