# How to clear command prompt in windows

Tags: mysql

Please can any one help me out how to clear the command prompt in windows while using mysql in command prompt

how can i clear the screen
Please can any one help me out how to clear the command prompt in windows while using mysql in command prompt

how can i clear the screen

Comment: The question was already asked an answered on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/585238/clear-windows-command-prompt-screen-using-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Jesus this question sounds desperate and urgent, I haven't wanted to 'clear the screen' so bad since my friend told me to google alaskan pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, it's not possible to do so in Windows. It's possible to do it in Linux (CTRL+L). You can only exit MySql, type in CLS, and re-enter MySql. 
See: [How to clear mysql screen console in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807836/how-to-clear-mysql-screen-console-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'cls' command to clear the screen in the window CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't provide direct commands to perform this. Linux has `ctrl+l` to do the same. But in windows, you have to exit MySQL with `\q` or `ctrl+c` and then use `CLS`  to clear your screen and login again to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it like this. it will work. try it please.

write a bat file

```
@mysql -uroot -p123456 -D%1 -e%2
```

named it mysqldb.bat.

then  use the bat:

```
mysqldb.bat dbname "select * from tablename;"
cls
```