# Clear unix terminal when running mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

Currently I'm working with mysql from and unix terminal and I can't use `clear` command to clean all the window because is a unix command not a mysql command.

I look in others questions [How to clear mysql screen console in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807836/how-to-clear-mysql-screen-console-in-windows) and [how to clear previously run queries in mysql command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997239/how-to-clear-previously-run-queries-in-mysql-command-prompt) to find any way that works on unix (I'm using ubuntu) and doesn't work. The way I do is log-out from mysql, apply the `clear` command on `$` prompt and relaunch `mysql` but its annoying.

**NOTE:** I also try `! clear` from mysql running but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `\!` to call shell commands with `clear`

```
\! clear
```